# Auto stretching vertical columns (divs)

Tags: html, css

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7MFX/2/) please:

I want the following: the red column has some text, the yellow is the dynamic content, the green has nothing, just a color. I want both red and green columns to be as height as the yellow content. `height: 100%` didnt work

Comment: You can use tables (but table is a bad practice, actually)

Comment: no tables sorry, I used to do it

Comment: Depending on the browser support needed, you could use [CSS3 flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) (not supported by IE9 or earlier).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use negative margins to achieve the result
[image]

The floating divs should be wrapped in a container with overflow:hidden
This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/FdXax/)
This is the code

```
#container {
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container div {
    padding-bottom:2000px;
    margin-bottom:-2000px;
}
```

Comment: nice, compatible with all browsers including ie7+

Comment: @Stano. Hy. Glad you like it.
IE7 have some problems when using negative margins but not under these circunstances. Problem with i7, as far as I know, arises if you pretend to see (overflow:visible) the  portion obtained with negative margins. in which case you should hacked with a relative positioned container.

Comment: +1 This [tested fine](https://litmus.com/pub/bf5ac41/screenshots) in all versions of IE (even IE6).

Answer (score 2):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7MFX/3/)

Not an easy solution but it works:

HTML

```
<div id="container3">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
            <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Got it from [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Comment: In the question, 2 of the columns appear to have variable widths. This approach doesn't support variable-width columns.

Comment: You should still be able to tweak it but you are right. Not best approach if you want variable width.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list instead.
You can display it as a *table-row* and the list-items as *table-cells* what makes all the list-items have the same height.

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7MFX/4/

Code:

```
<ul style="list-style:none;padding:0;display:table-row">
    <li style="display:table-cell;background-color: red;">11<br>11<br>11<br></li>
    <li style="display:table-cell;background-color: yellow;">22342<br>dsfsdf<br>sdfs df<br>v sdfsdf s dffffffffffffffff</li>
    <li style="display:table-cell;background-color: green; width: 40px;">11</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't use lists for styling purposes. Lists should contain ordered/unordered information lists or definitions. Use the div element instead: http://jsfiddle.net/hDAuf/

Comment: @chaenu You're totally right! The main thing I wanted to communicate though was the `display:table-row` approach. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/9XVSr/

html:

```
<div class="col" id="col1" style="background-color: red; float: left">11<br>11<br>11<br></div>
<div class="col" id="col2" style="background-color: yellow; float: left">22342<br>dsfsdf<br>sdfs df<br>v sdfsdf s dffffffffffffffff</div>
<div class="col" id="col3" style="background-color: green; width: 40px; float: right">11</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
maxcol = Math.max($('#col1').height(),$('#col2').height(),$('#col3').height());
$('.col').height(maxcol);    
});
```

Comment: if you want a one liner:
`$('.col').height(Math.max.apply(Math, $(".col").map(function() { return $(this).height(); })));`