# Make a div take up remaining vertical space of a parent container.

Tags: html, css

How can I get the "content" `<div>` of these two columns to fill the container's entire height?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m4f7/8/

This is a follow up to this question: [Make children divs the height of tallest child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594891/make-children-divs-the-height-of-tallest-child).

Here is a similar question, but the solutions don't seem to work. 
[Make div (height) occupy parent remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225912/make-div-height-occupy-parent-remaining-height)

Comment: Take a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: A similar solution as this one I published could be implemented in your example if it is ok for you to float your divs. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545531/auto-stretching-vertical-columns-divs/16545816#16545816.   I can apply something similar for your example... .

Comment: How critical is your HTML? Your current mark-up will not make this possible using CSS alone.  However, there is hope.  How critical are the borders? And can I make some minor changes to the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the display:inline-block, I used floats.
In order to obtain the same height , I used the content div to push the item div through the padding/margin compensation.
The background color of the title and content are now independent. You can changed at will.
The automatic margin between the inline-block elements can be replaced with regular margins applied to the divs at will or if you prefer just take them away.
You get the following:
[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/tDFJW/)

markup did not change
Css as follows

```
.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.item {   
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px; 
}

.title, .content {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.content  {
       padding-bottom:1000px;
    margin-bottom:-1000px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.title {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: That's literally the sickest CSS trick I've seen in a while. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe this is sufficient. When you add `vertical-align: top;`, the top edges will align nicely

```
.item {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPfGC/)